# Hacer un SUM con codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Necesito sumar los datos de tabla detalle el problema esque no contiene la fecha si no en tabla principal, lo hacia muy facil de la siguiente forma:
Modelo:

```
$this->db->select('COALESCE(SUM(cajas),0) as total_cajas, COALESCE(SUM(peso),0) as total_peso, COALESCE(SUM(precio),0) as total_precio');
```

todo bien hasta alli me podria retornar correctamente la informacion pero TODA!. el problema es que quiero traerlo por fecha intente con :

```
        $this->db->select('a.peso,a.cajas,a.precio, b.fecha');
        $this->db->from('separacion_detalles a');
        $this->db->join('separacion b','a.idseparacion = b.id');
        $this->db->where('b.fecha',$año.$dia);
        $result = $this->db->get();
        return $result->row();
```

todo bien tambien, el problema esque donde pongo la sumatoria de cajas,peso,precio?

Comment: Amigo mira si esto te sirve de algo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25992028/8933039

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando no puedas realizar una consulta en Codeigniter a través de sus funciones puedes utilizar `$this->db->query($sql);` solo pon en `$sql` la consulta que necesitas:

```
    function obtener($parametros){
        $sql="COALESCE(SUM(a.cajas),0) as total_cajas, 
        COALESCE(SUM(a.peso),0) as total_peso, 
        COALESCE(SUM(a.precio),0) as total_precio
        from separacion_detalles a inner join separacion b 
        on a.idseparacion = b.id
        where b.fecha = '$año.dia'";
        $consulta = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $consulta->row_array();
    }
```

De esa forma puedes realizar cualquier consulta, espero te sea de ayuda, no te compliques, saludos.